# Day 20: Sorting in Hackerrank, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, bubble-sort

recently I have been doing HackerRank 30 days of code challenge and solve the challenge using Python. However in day 20(about Bubble Sort algorithm) I cannot solve it. This is the [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-sorting) to the task in Hackerrank and below is my code.

```
import sys

n = int(raw_input().strip())
a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
numSwap = 0

for first in a:
    b = a[a.index(first)+1:]
    for second in b:
        if first > second:
            a[a.index(first)] = second
            a[a.index(second)] = first
            numSwap += 1

firstElement = a[0]
lastElement = a[len(a)-1]
print "Array is sorted in %d swaps\nFirst Element: %s\nLast Element: %d " %(numSwap, firstElement, lastElement)
```

The input for this code is:

> 3
>   3 2 1

The result of the code is:

```
Array is sorted in 3 swaps  
First Element: 3  
Last Element: 1
```

The expected result:

```
Array is sorted in 3 swaps.
First Element: 1
Last Element: 3
```

the question is why it did not work like expected? which part of the code is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The swapping is the erroneous part unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code and the reason why it isn't working as expected is because:

```
for first in a:
b = a[a.index(first)+1:]
for second in b:
    if first > second:
        a[a.index(first)] = second
        a[a.index(second)] = first
        numSwap += 1
```

you are swapping the elements in the first array, `a`, but aren't updating the same in the second array, `b`.

Here's a solution that should work flawlessly:

```
import sys

n = int(raw_input().strip())
a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
# Write Your Code Here
numberOfSwaps = 0
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n-1):
        if a[j] > a[j+1]:
            a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]
            numberOfSwaps += 1
    if not numberOfSwaps:
        break


print "Array is sorted in", numberOfSwaps, "swaps."
print "First Element:", a[0]
print "Last Element:", a[n-1]
```

Cheers :)

Comment: I'm not updating the `b` list so that the `first` variable will still be compared to the other elements in the list. Thank you for the solution, I already know about that, but I still confused why mine don't works.

Comment: if the solution that I provided worked, then do upvote and accept it as an answer :)

Comment: I'm still confused why my code not working actually and your explanation did not satisfy me. I did not understand why should I update the `b` list that you mentioned because `b` list supposed to make the `first` variable to compared to other elements in `b` list.

Answer (score 0):

I finally know what is the mistake in my code.

```
for first in a:
    b = a[a.index(first)+1:]
    for second in b:
        if first > second:
            a[a.index(first)] = second
            a[a.index(second)] = first
            numSwap += 1
```

so these code below is swapping back the elements to its original place:

```
a[a.index(first)] = second
a[a.index(second)] = first
```

should have created a variable to contain one of the elements.

```
smaller = a.index(first)
bigger = a.index(second)
a[smaller] = second
a[bigger] = big
```

and my second mistake is the first `for` will not repeat the algorithm from the newly updated list causing the 2 as the first element.

the correct code is as written by TheDarkKnight.

> Here's a solution that should work flawlessly:
>
> ```
> import sys
>
> n = int(raw_input().strip())
> a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
> # Write Your Code Here
> numberOfSwaps = 0
> for i in xrange(n):
>     for j in xrange(n-1):
>         if a[j] > a[j+1]:
>             a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]
>             numberOfSwaps += 1
>     if not numberOfSwaps:
>         break
>
>
> print "Array is sorted in", numberOfSwaps, "swaps."
> print "First Element:", a[0]
> print "Last Element:", a[n-1]
> ```
>
> Cheers :)